# How can I iterate the first half of a Hash in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a Hash such as:

```
{
    "ruby": 5,
    "python": 4, 
    "java": 3,
    "js": 2,
    "php", 1
}
```

I know how to iterate the Hash:

```
<% languages.each for |key, value| %>

<% end %>
```

I want to iterate the first half part of this Hash, I can get the size of Hash with `languages.length`, but `languages[i]` seems return nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by"first half"? Could you show the expected output?

Comment: @Stefan, in fact, i want to get{"ruby": 5, "python": 4, "java": 3} first, then I want to get {"js": 2, "php": 1}

Answer (score 3):

> in fact, i want to get `{"ruby": 5, "python": 4, "java": 3}` first, then I want to get `{"js": 2, "php": 1}`

Rails provides a [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) method, but you have to convert `languages` into an array:

```
languages = { ruby: 5, python: 4, java: 3, js: 2, php: 1 }.to_a

languages.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group|
  group.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} = #{value}"
  end
  puts '---'
end
```

Output:

```
ruby = 5
python = 4
java = 3
---
js = 2
php = 1
---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a set of keys:

```
keys = myhash.keys[0, myhash.length / 2]
```

Then you can select the hash entries for those keys:

```
firsthalf = myhash.select {|key,value| keys.include?(key) }
```

This gives you a copy of the first half of the hash that you can iterate, push to a view to iterate there, etc.  However, if this is a really large hash that you don't want to copy, it's best to iterate as above and just stop when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

here is a fast way:

```
languages.first(languages.length / 2).each do |k, v|
   # Do what ever you want here
end
```

this is because the hash elements are in the order of which their keys have been inserted.

And to respond to your comment

> @Stefan, in fact, i want to get{"ruby": 5, "python": 4, "java": 3}
>   first, then I want to get {"js": 2, "php": 1}

You can use [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
 slice_size = 3
 languages.each_slice(slice_size) do |slice|
     slice.each do |key, value|
        # do what you want with each element in the slice
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each_with_index, it will loop through collection and provider current element index

```
<% languages.each_with_index for |value, index| %>

<% end %>
```